# Applying heuristic to recursive backtracking

Tags: c++, algorithm

Searched for other problems -- and there are similar ones, but none that deal with this particular heuristic.

I have working code for a problem which asks to take a vector into some function, determine whether any values in that vector sum up to a given target value, and then returns whether it does or not (boolean). This is simple.

I have to use the backtracking heuristic supplied to create this function (below), which is working correctly in principle. I have to ensure that my function is not generating combinations which have been generated before (ABC is the same as BAC, for instance). How do I prevent my code from doing this? I cannot change the parameters going into the function **(so the function prototype has to remain as it is below)**, but wrapper or helper functions are OK.

Here is the heuristic:

```
  bool Solve(configuration conf) {
       if (no more choices) // BASE CASE
         return (conf is goal state);

  for (all available choices) {

        try one choice c;
        // recursively solve after making choice

  ok = Solve(conf with choice c made);
   if (ok) return true;
   else unmake choice c;

   }
   return false; // tried all choices, no soln found
  }
```

My code:

```
bool CanMakeSum(Vector<int> & nums, int targetSum) {

if (nums.isEmpty()) { 

    cout << "you've reached the target sum" << endl;
    return true;

} else {

    for (int i  = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {

        element = nums[i];
        Vector<int> rest = nums;
        cout << "list the subset: " << listSubset(rest) << endl;
        rest.removeAt(i);

        // try one          
        int new_target_sum = targetSum - element;

        CanMakeSum(rest, new_target_sum);

            if (new_target_sum == 0) {
                return true;

            } else {

            new_target_sum = targetSum + element;

        }
    }
}

return false;
}


string listSubset(Vector<int> &partial_solution) {

string solution = " ";

for (int i = 0; i < partial_solution.size(); i++) {
    solution += IntegerToString(partial_solution[i]) + " ";
}

return solution;

}
```

Comment: BTW, your code is different than the pseudo code.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks -- what am I missing?

Comment: You didn't translate `return (conf is goal state);` and `ok = Solve(conf with choice c made);` correctly.

Comment: @Jarod42 -- Right, I see that now. It's just I'm really unsure what that would look like. My guess would be some change involved in new_target_sum = targetSum - element? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce ordering in choosing elements. For example after choosing ith element you cannot choose any element with index less than i. Change required in code is that after choosing ith element you need to remove all elements from index 0 to i.

Comment: Isn't that what is already being done at rest.removeAt(i)? How would your suggestion look in pseudocode?

Comment: I think rest.removeAt(i) removes ith element. If you remove all elements from 0 to i you can either get A before B or B before A not both.

Comment: For example if B comes after A and if you choose B you remove A hence you cannot choose A after B.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for where/how I would implement removing all the elements from 0 to i? Just not sure where to put that. Thanks.

Comment: If you declare rest before for loop it will automatically remove all elements till i.

Comment: Remove this line from inside Vector<int> rest = nums; and write it outside.

Comment: Equivalently, and a bit more efficiently, you can get rid of the `for` loop entirely, set `rest` to all but the last element of `nums`, and just make 2 recursive calls: `return CanMakeSum(rest, targetSum) || CanMakeSum(rest, targetSum - nums.back());`. Rationale: the final element must be either included or excluded from the subset.

Comment: @j_random_hacker We have to use the for loop in this problem, unfortunately. It is a rewrite of the code you have mentioned above with only the for loops and the two parameters mentioned above.